# What does "low sea level" mean?

Tags: civilization-5

This term comes in advanced settings without any more explanation. Does this mean I will get more water if I chose low sea level or more mountainous terrain? Or maybe I am misunderstanding the term completely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that this means it will lower the overall sea level for the world causing more terrain to be exposed for your troops.

Comment: More specifically, lowers the water/land ratio.